Power Automate Access Issue
I am creating a Power Apps app using a Power Automate flow. There are SharePoint, Excel, and Office 365 Users connections. Everything goes as planned on my end, but when a user tries to use the app, they receive an error saying "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server."
When I look at the flow, the problem occurs at "List rows present in a table" through Excel. The issue is that "The resource could not be found." The user is not able to access the Excel file and is not a member of the Teams team / SharePoint server the file is stored in. However, the user is a run-only user for the Excel Online and Office 365 Users connections, and all actions occur via my connection.
Does anyone have a solution for my issue? I am happy to provide more specifics as necessary.
I have kept trying to make slight adjustments, and have republished the app after each change, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

this is the expected behavior: a user should not be able to edit a resource (the xls) if he/she does not have permission to edit it. :)
The problem is, that the canvas app runs as the logged in user. I would use a technical Sharepoint list as a workaround. You have mentioned that you use Sharepoint here as well, so an additional tech list should not be a problem.
Steps in high level:

the app is not editing the final xls, but add rows to the technical SPO list (lets name it 'TaskQueue').
The app does not run the flow directly.
The flow's trigger should be creating a new item in this TaskQueue list.
This TaskQueue list should have all the parameters, to execute the flow (or need a key to the original list, or you can put everything into a single JSON code)

With this approach, the flow's owner need to have edit permission to the final xls.

Thanks for the response! The point of creating this app is because I do not want users to be able to see the xls since it contains information about all users, but I want them to see their individual information. Do you have a solution for this?

Yes, the approach I wrote fits for this scenario: users of the app need to have contribute permission just for this technical list (or, if it is necessary, you can set an "add-only" permission level for them). The final xls need to be writeable only by the user of the owner of the flow. In the technical spo list you can set (under the list settings > advanced settings), that everybody can see only those list items which are created by themself.

Ah I see. Is it possible to make it so a list can be updated any time the xls is updated? Probably using another flow, right?

I'm afraid there are no trigger option for Excel row modification for flows. Maybe you can store the data in an other SPO list.

My team would really prefer to keep storing our data in an xls. I thought it would be easy to have a way for users to see only their row of data, whether that is in the format of an individual xls or an app, while taking data from a main xls sheet that is hidden from them. Is there really no easy way to do this?

I think you can't use the Excel on this way. Other idea, but it has not too much sense, that you make a canvas app, which looks like a spreadsheet. In this case, you have again the ability to set row level permissions.

I appreciate all of your help and patience. Everything I try doesn't work because users don't have access to the main xls but I also can't let them see the whole thing (only their row). I can't figure out a way to get around the access issue
